# How to test parallely in 2 diffrent Real Android Device using Appium

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I am able to test a particular app in real android device, but now I have a different requirement:-

I have a requirement in which I need to test two mobile apps in two different android devices on the same machine parallelly. How to achieve this?

To start the hub I did something like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub
```

-nodeTimeout 600

Now we need to open the node and then with that particular node we need to communicate in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with this command you create central hub for communication. Now you must launch Appium nodes associated with this hub (hub IP address in the `-nodeConfig` parameter file). Appium nodes will automatically connect to the hub and you just need to make requests to the hub and hub will direct the session to the correct node.

More info here: [Appium node servers with Selenium Grid](http://blog.zymr.com/configuring-appium-node-servers-with-selenium-grid)

Comment: in the link which u provided after that json file creation we need to do something like:- `node.exe node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js --nodeconfig <path to appium_node_S4.json> -p 4723 –U 192.168.56.101:5555` i am not not able to understand the each section

Comment: This command means that you launch Appium node with predefined configuration in file `-nodeConfig`, port `-p`, device UDID `-U`, and here is missing bootstrap port too `-bp` which must differ from port parameter.

Comment: can you please give the exact command to start the node on two diffrent port and then register it to hub

Comment: `node appium --nodeconfig <path_to_JSON> -p 4712 --udid <device_udid> -bp 4722`